# jQuery slide menu newbie

Tags: jquery, css, html, menu, slide

Been learning jQuery today and have managed to make myself this slide menu, I was just wondering if there is a way to make the code more simplified?

http://jsfiddle.net/jkuVG/2/

Doesn't seem to work in the jsfiddle? but when you click about me, projects etc a box appears underneath..

Can this be made shorter to reduce the css or jquery code (or both) like using the same class for each different box would be good...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#box1").click(function() {
    $('.dropbox').slideToggle("slow");
 });
  $("#box2").click(function() {
    $('.dropbox2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
    $("#box3").click(function() {
    $('.dropbox3').slideToggle("slow");
 });
});
```

Comment: you forgot to add jquery library, here a fix to you jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jkuVG/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn the `ids` to just a common class names and attach just one handler to it.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>About me</p>
</div>
<div class="dropbox">
    <p>a wild potato appeared</p>
</div>
<div class="box">Projects</div>
<div class="dropbox">
    <p>ja</p>
</div>
<div class="box">Websites</div>
<div class="dropbox">
    <p>hey</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.dropbox').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box:first-child{
     margin-top: 20px;
}
.box {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 470px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.box:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.dropbox {
    max-width: 470px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
    color: white;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rgCLv/)**

And btw you need to select jquery in your fiddle, from the left panel "Frameworks & Extensions".

And if you want to slideup other when toggling the current dropbox you can just do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $dropBoxes = $('.dropbox');
    $(".box").click(function () {
        $dropBoxes.not($(this).next('.dropbox').slideToggle("slow")).slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: @CallamWarner-Billington You are welcome. Hope this is what you were looking for?

Comment: Yep, It's teached me something new (and will help in the future). I knew it was possible to make it shorter just wasn't sure how, so thanks again!